# Parsing JSON data and inserting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

So basically I want to parse a JSON file in PHP and insert the data into specific tables/columns. At the moment I have a working script but requires me to modify the JSON largely until it works. However, it won't end up working because the JSON data I'm collecting can vary in size having more data rows.

The JSON file is structured differently to most I have seen. Maybe because its output data from sensor units. I want to insert the data and the serial number into the data table, and have an error_log table where I can store the serial number and error messages as strings. How can I achieve this?

**JSON** File:

```
{
   "device": {
      "sn": 5165654,
      "name": "FDI_AWS_DEMO",
      "v": "2.7B3"
   },
   "channels": [
      {
         "code": "RH",
         "name": "Relative Humidity",
         "unit": "%"
      },
      {
         "code": "AT",
         "name": "Air Temperature",
         "unit": "C"
      },
      {
         "code": "MINVi",
         "name": "Min voltage",
         "unit": "V"
      },
      {
         "code": "PTi",
         "name": "Processor temperature",
         "unit": "C"
      },
      {
         "code": "SDB",
         "name": "Network signal dB",
         "unit": "dB"
      },
      {
         "code": "LWS",
         "name": "Leaf Wetness",
         "unit": "%"
      },
      {
         "code": "WSAV",
         "name": "Wind Speed Avg",
         "unit": "km/h"
      },
      {
         "code": "WSMX",
         "name": "Wind Speed Max",
         "unit": "km/h"
      },
      {
         "code": "WSMN",
         "name": "Wind Speed Min",
         "unit": "km/h"
      },
      {
         "code": "PR_TOT",
         "name": "PR Tot",
         "unit": "mm"
      },
      {
         "code": "RAIN",
         "name": "Rain",
         "unit": "mm"
      },
      {
         "code": "FDI",
         "name": "fdi",
         "unit": "Unit"
      },
      {
         "code": "DT",
         "name": "Delta-T",
         "unit": "C"
      },
      {
         "code": "LAT",
         "name": "Latitude",
         "unit": "deg"
      },
      {
         "code": "LON",
         "name": "Longitude",
         "unit": "deg"
      },
      {
         "code": "WD",
         "name": "Wind Direction",
         "unit": "Degrees"
      },
      {
         "code": "P1",
         "name": "Par1",
         "unit": ""
      },
      {
         "code": "AVGCi",
         "name": "Average Current",
         "unit": "mA"
      },
      {}
   ],
   "data": [
      {
         "$ts": 170801164400,
         "$msg": "SD_FAIL;1"
      },
      {
         "$ts": 170801170000,
         "$msg": "WDT;WV01"
      },
      {
         "$ts": 170801170000,
         "$msg": "WDT;SDI12"
      },
      {
         "$ts": 170801170000,
         "$msg": "WDT;LWS"
      },
      {
         "$ts": 170801170000,
         "RH": 67.15,
         "AT": 12.87,
         "MINVi": 3.81,
         "PTi": 23.4,
         "LWS": "0*T",
         "WSAV": 0,
         "WSMX": 0,
         "WSMN": 0,
         "PR_TOT": 156,
         "RAIN": 0,
         "FDI": 0.239,
         "DT": 2.881,
         "WD": "0*T",
         "P1": "0*T",
         "AVGCi": 175
      },
      {}
   ]
}
```

**PHP** Code:

```
<?php
    //connect to mysql db
    $myConnection= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","******", "ii") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

    //read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('test.json');

    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    $id = $data['device']['sn'];
    $ts = $data['data']['$ts'];
    $RH = $data['data']['RH'];
    $AT = $data['data']['AT'];
    $MINVi = $data['data']['MINVi'];
    $PTi = $data['data']['PTi'];
    $SDB = $data['data']['SDB'];
    $LWS = $data['data']['LWS'];
    $WSAV = $data['data']['WSAV'];
    $WSMX = $data['data']['WSMX'];
    $WSMN = $data['data']['WSMN'];
    $PR_TOT = $data['data']['PR_TOT'];
    $RAIN = $data['data']['RAIN'];
    $FDI = $data['data']['FDI'];
    $DT = $data['data']['DT'];
    $LAT = $data['data']['LAT'];
    $LON = $data['data']['LON'];
    $WD = $data['data']['WD'];
    $P1 = $data['data']['P1'];
    $AVGCi = $data['data']['AVGCi'];



    //insert into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test(sn, date, RH, AT, MINVi, PTi, SDB, LWS, WSAV, WSMX, WSMN, PR_TOT, RAIN, FDI, DT, LAT, LON, WD, P1, AVGCi)
    VALUES('$id', '$ts', '$RH','$AT', '$MINVi', '$PTi', '$SDB', '$LWS', '$WSAV', '$WSMX', '$WSMN', '$PR_TOT', '$RAIN', '$FDI', '$DT', '$LAT', '$LON', '$WD', '$P1', '$AVGCi')";


 $query=mysqli_query($myConnection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection)); 
?>
```

**Tables** Test data table and error_log table

[image: Table Screenshot]

JSON array var_dump - [JSON var dump](https://puu.sh/xtraV/ddef37ea87.png)

Any help would be great

(After i get the general gist i want to incorporate PDO)

Comment: whats the actual error?

Comment: Not so much of an error, more of a question for help ? I cant parse the names and values to my tables unless the file is modified, which isn't efficient. Is there an easier way to parse the JSON data and insert into the tables?

Comment: what modifications to the file makes it work?

Comment: removing Channels , each ts and message part from data and then changing square brackets to regular brackets. Quite a process i know aha..

Comment: can you do a `vardump` on the `$data` so we see the nested structure of the parsed `json`

Comment: Sure , here you go - https://puu.sh/xtraV/ddef37ea87.png

Comment: change the `$ts` to `ts`  and `$msg` to `msg`

Comment: That' how they are named in the raw JSON file?

Comment: Your JSON 'data' key is array so why you access elements from that array as it would one of object inside array, you should rather do 
`$data['data'][0]['RH']`. There are many objects in that array under data key, so if you want to ditch those that have no keys you need then do that. Does each row of data has either only {ts, msg} and {ts, RH, AH, ...}, or it will vary a lot?

Comment: I had no idea you could specify the location of the code/value in the array e.g $data['data'][0]['RH'], thanks for clearing that up.  yes each row will only have ts, msg and ts,RH, AH,.. Sometimes a new code will be added to the ts,RH,AH.. , it wont vary a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not convert json to associative array blindly. It creates more problems.
2. For accessing properties containing special characters or reserved
   words use placeholders like `$data->{'$ts'}`
3. Loop through arrays and objects if needed.
4. Adding an auto increment `id` column to tables helps to store data
   for one device.
5. It is a good idea to add `time` to `error_log` table as well

Tested bellow short version of your original question and it works.

```
<?php
        $_user = 'root';
        $_password= 'root';
        $_db = 'localtest';
        $_host = 'localhost';
        $_port = 3306;
    $con = new mysqli($_host, $_user, $_password, $_db) or die(mysql_error);

    //read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('test.json');

    //do not convert to array
    $json = json_decode($jsondata);

    $id = $json->device->sn;
    foreach($json->data as $key => $data){
        if(empty($data) || !isset($data->{'$ts'})){
            continue;
        }
        if (isset($data->{'$msg'})){
            $msg = $data->{'$msg'};
            $time = $data->{'$ts'};

            $sql="INSERT into error_log (sn, time, MSG) VALUES (?,?,?); ";
            $stmt = $con-> prepare($sql);
            $stmt -> bind_param("iss", $id,$time, $msg);
            $stmt -> execute();
        }else{
            $time = (isset($data->{'$ts'}))? $data->{'$ts'}:'';
            $RH = (isset($data->RH))? $data->RH:'';
            $AT = (isset($data->AT))? $data->AT:'';
            $MINVi = (isset($data->MINVi))? $data->MINVi:'';

            //insert into mysql table
            $sql="INSERT into test (sn, date, RH, AT, MINVi) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?); ";
            $stmt = $con-> prepare($sql);
            $stmt -> bind_param("issss", $id,$time,$RH,$AT,$MINVi);
            $stmt -> execute();
        }


    }
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response N Moeini! I gave the code a crack and got this error - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean for this line $stmt -> bind_param("iss", $id,$time, $msg);

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be good to store time in error_log as well. Your schema does not match. Add time column to your table or remove it from sql and bind_param

Comment: Worked like a charm, didn't even think bout logging time. Thanks mate you are a genius.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please accept the answer to help others. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. For future reference if there is every to be more data fields added can i just add them to the existing code such  $sql="INSERT into test (sn, date, RH, AT, MINVi,NEW1,NEW2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?); "; Keeping in mind to make changes to bind_param and $NEW1 = $data -> NEW1;  $NEW2 = $data -> NEW2;

Comment: Great answer! But @hokletrain - didn't you need a more dynamic SQL as some of those columns may not always show up in json feeds. For instance, *SDB*, *LON*, *LAT* do not appear but you attempt to pass in query.

Comment: @Parfait I have updated the answer to be safe in using object's properties.

Comment: Great! Consider using `null` instead of zero-length string since OP's table include numbers. But MySQL might allow I believe.

Comment: Okay so i just realised that time doesn't get imported properly. Instead it comes up as 2147483647 every time?

Comment: Never mind i found out what was happening.. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Consider building dynamic SQL calls conditionally depending on the error output. The array keys create the columns in `INSERT` clause and array values are quote wrapped in `VALUES` clause. Below echoes the sql statements just to demonstrate.

This should work for *any* change to JSON suffice no other new keys are added. Also, the `array_splice` is used to remove the *$ts* value the second time since you pass it in *date* column.

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('Input.json');

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$id = $data['device']['sn'];

foreach ($data['data'] as $k=>$v){
    if (array_key_exists("\$msg",$v) & !empty($v)){
       $sql = "INSERT INTO error_log (sn, msg)" 
              ." VALUES('$id', '". $v["\$msg"] ."')";
       echo $sql."\n";
       // INSERT INTO error_log (sn, msg) VALUES('5165654', 'SD_FAIL;1')
       // INSERT INTO error_log (sn, msg) VALUES('5165654', 'WDT;WV01')
       // INSERT INTO error_log (sn, msg) VALUES('5165654', 'WDT;SDI12')
       // INSERT INTO error_log (sn, msg) VALUES('5165654', 'WDT;LWS')

       $query = mysqli_query(...);
    } 
    if (!array_key_exists("\$msg",$v) & !empty($v)) {
       $keysArray = array_keys($v);
       $keysArray = array_splice($keysArray, 1);
       $vVals = array_splice($v, 1);

       $sql = "INSERT INTO test(sn, date, ". implode(", ", $keysArray) .")\n" 
              ." VALUES('$id', '". $v['$ts'] ."',". implode("', '", $vVals) .")";
       echo $sql."\n";

       // INSERT INTO test(sn, date, RH, AT, MINVi, PTi, LWS, WSAV, WSMX, WSMN,
       // PR_TOT, RAIN, FDI, DT, WD, P1, AVGCi)
       // VALUES('5165654', '170801170000',67.15', '12.87', '3.81', '23.4', '0*T',
       //  '0', '0', '0', '156', '0', '0.239', '2.881', '0*T', '0*T', '175)

       $query=mysqli_query(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the help parfait. I could then just have mysqli_query($myConnection, $sql); at the bottom of each statement to then execute the query replacing $query=mysqli_query(...) ?

Comment: Exactly. The dots are just placeholders. Did you test it out? Again, no need to `echo` as here was just demonstration. Also, consider adding date to your *error_log* table with `$ts` values.

Comment: I tested your code @parfait , it inserts into the error_log table well but doesn't insert anything into the data table ? :/

Answer (score 0):

looks like the json decode is turning the array into one that is object based...run the $data through the function below to turn it into more of a relational array that is setup the way you are trying to read it....

I cannot find the function i had for this at the moment but If you read the array more like this:

```
$newvar = $data->node;

//to echo this try this...
echo '<pre style="text-align:left;">';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

OR try fb logs for php to see the arrays in console of ya browser - use firephp for the addon.

it should work just fine...

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can get you on track... One thing I did notice is there doesn't appear to be an `SDB` entry in the given JSON data (FYI).

```
<?php
//connect to mysql db
$myConnection= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","******", "ii") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('test.json');

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

// Make sure $data has values
if (empty($data)) {
  // Process error here
}
else {
  // Make sure the proper keys have been set
  if (!(isset($data['device']) && !empty($data['device']) && isset($data['data']) && !empty($data['data']))) {
    // Process error here if not set
  }
  // If so, make sure the sn key has been set
  elseif (!isset($data['device']['sn']) || empty($data['device']['sn'])) {
    // Process error here if not set
  }
  else {        
    $data_arr = $data['data'];

    foreach ($data_arr as $key => $arr) {
      // Iterate through for loop
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($data_arr); $i++) {
        // Make sure every single key is set
        if (!(isset($data_arr[$i]['$ts']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['RH']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['AT']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['MINVi']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['PTi']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['SDB']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['LWS']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['WSAV']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['WSMX']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['WSMN']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['PR_TOT']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['RAIN']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['FDI']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['DT']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['LAT']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['LON']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['WD']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['P1']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['AVGCi']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['DT']) && isset($data_arr[$i]['DT']))) {
          // Process error here if not set
        }
        else {
          // If all is well, perform the query
          $id[$key][$i] = $arr['device']['sn'];
          $ts[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['$ts'];
          $RH[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['RH'];
          $AT[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['AT'];
          $MINVi[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['MINVi'];
          $PTi[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['PTi'];
          $SDB[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['SDB'];
          $LWS[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['LWS'];
          $WSAV[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['WSAV'];
          $WSMX[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['WSMX'];
          $WSMN[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['WSMN'];
          $PR_TOT[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['PR_TOT'];
          $RAIN[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['RAIN'];
          $FDI[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['FDI'];
          $DT[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['DT'];
          $LAT[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['LAT'];
          $LON[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['LON'];
          $WD[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['WD'];
          $P1[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['P1'];
          $AVGCi[$key][$i] = $data_arr[$i]['AVGCi'];

          $sql[$key][$i] = "INSERT INTO test(sn, date, RH, AT, MINVi, PTi, SDB, LWS, WSAV, WSMX, WSMN, PR_TOT, RAIN, FDI, DT, LAT, LON, WD, P1, AVGCi)
          VALUES('{$id[$key][$i]}', '{$ts[$key][$i]}', '{$RH[$key][$i]}','{$AT[$key][$i]}', '{$MINVi[$key][$i]}', '{$PTi[$key][$i]}', '{$SDB[$key][$i]}', '{$LWS[$key][$i]}', '{$WSAV[$key][$i]}', '{$WSMX[$key][$i]}', '{$WSMN[$key][$i]}', '{$PR_TOT[$key][$i]}', '{$RAIN[$key][$i]}', '{$FDI[$key][$i]}', '{$DT[$key][$i]}', '{$LAT[$key][$i]}', '{$LON[$key][$i]}', '{$WD[$key][$i]}', '{$P1[$key][$i]}', '{$AVGCi[$key][$i]}')";

          //insert into mysql table
          $query[$key][$i] = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sql[$key][$i]) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```